# Stylesheet link renders with very wrong path

Tags: ee2

I'm working on a site using EE 2.8.1. I have links for CSS files using EE stylesheet links, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{stylesheet=global/main.css}">
```

Never had an issue with this approach before, but when pages are served up it's coming out as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://domain.dev///////////////////?css=global/main.css">
```

What could be the cause of this? Any tips greatly appreciated!

(Site is also using Structure, and .htaccess rewrite to remove index.php from URLs -- also a combination I've used before with stylesheet links with no problems.)

Answer (score 1):

At a guess this looks like an htaccess rewrite problem. (do you need the .css on the filename?)

Personally I'd say unless you are using some EE tags in your stylesheets then don't link them up that way and just link to them normally. You're simply adding to the processing required to render your site.

That will, most likely, also stop the problem you're having.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{site_url}global/main.css">` if you needed a full url for some reason

Comment: Or just use <link rel="stylesheet" href="/global/main.css">